# Why the ach form is_bound always false?

Tags: django

i trying to update a modelform while save another modelform, I want to update ach form with the new value from the Payments forms, the ach from is always unbound ??

forms.py :

```
  achat = get_object_or_404(Achats,pk=pk)
  form = Payments_Form(request.POST or None,achat_id=pk)
  if form.is_valid():
            ach = AchatForm(instance=achat)
            ach.fields['Montant_pay'] = form.cleaned_data['Montant_TTC']
            if ach.is_valid():
                ach.fields['Montant_pay'] = form.cleaned_data['Montant_TTC']
                ach.save()
            print(ach.errors)
            print(ach.is_bound)
            form.save()
            return redirect('view')
```

forms.py :

```
class AchatForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Achats
        fields = ('Date','Id_Fournis','Montant_HT','Montant_TVA','Montant_TTC','Montant_pay')

class Payments_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payements
        fields = ('Date', 'mode_de_payement', 'reference', 'Montant_HT','Montant_TVA','Montant_TTC', 'Numero_facture', 'Numero_payement','E_S')
```

Comment: Because you do not make a POST request.

Comment: or in the case of the `AchatForm`, because you do not pass data (`request.POST`) for example.

Comment: in the first time i did  ach = AchatForm(request.POST,instance=achat) , then i get an error : '''decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'disabled'' , both fields Montant_pay and Montant_TTC are DecimalField so what the probleme

Comment: well they likely do not appear in the `request.POST` data, but are required.

Comment: i kind lost here, i want to update the ach form with the new value from the Payments from , any suggestion  ?